# Is starting cash too low?

Tags: character-creation, wealth, exodus-rpg

In *[Exodus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exodus_(role-playing_game))* starting cash seems lower than in other games with which I'm familiar. I'm used to starting characters being able to purchase some okay weapons and armor, and that seems unlikely given the small amount of credits granted by a character's occupation.

Is this a problem in play? Should I offset this by giving PCs weapons if the weapons pertain to their jobs (like a soldier for example) or just figure *tough luck and hope you survive*?

Answer (score 8):

It is not.

## This is one of the major aspects of the game!

Like in many postapocalyptic games, you start with trashy equipment and manage to get some better stuff by mainly stealing, divesting your dead enemies from their equipment, exploring and searching wrecks.

Strictly talking about **Exodus**, you are not even allowed to purchase anything good, according to the rules.

> Beginning  characters  may  only  purchase equipment of Common or Uncommon Scarcity.

Starting wealth should be enough to get equipment fitting their chosen occupation. Better stuff has to be earned, so PCs will really appreciate it.

Comment: I fully agree with this answer. However, I would like to note that in both of our Exodus campaigns, our DM has given us at least some guns and ammo to start out with.

Answer (score 0):

When I DM, I usually have my players come up with a back story, and depending on whats in it, I usually start them with certain items or more money. Find it helps get them off on a good foot, unless of course you really want them to strive and scrape money together. I have played exodus once, and our DM started us all with a set amount, the same for everyone. It worked out great.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! When you get a moment, give the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) a look. Personal experience is great, though if you know any *other* references that can support your answer, that can sometimes be an improvement.

Comment: Does Exodus actually call this position "DM", or do they have another term? Usually "DM" is a term reserved exclusively for the context of D&D games (indeed, Dungeon Master is a Wizards of the Coast trademark). It's helpful and demonstrates expertise to refer to the actual name the game uses for the equivalent.